# How does google do the barrel roll?

Tags: css, google-search

If you Google, 'do a barrel roll', the whole page does a 360 rotation. Does anyone have any guesses as to how Google is doing this? I disabled javascript, and it still occurred, so maybe a css rotation?

Comment: It's most likely CSS rotation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you look at the css code :

```
body {
    -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-name: roll;
}
```

Comment: where roll is something like 
@-webkit-keyframes roll {

 from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0); }

 to   { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }

}

Comment: Obnoxious JavaScript animations are dead! All hail obnoxious CSS animations!

Answer (score 16):

As said above, with CSS3 animations and transform.

Wesbo showed a way to apply the effect on any site. You can view a demo and instruction [here](http://sumtips.com/2011/11/make-any-site-do-a-barrel-roll.html).

```
@-webkit-keyframes roll {
from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) }
to   { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) }
}

@-moz-keyframes roll {
from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) }
to   { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) }
}

@keyframes roll {
from { transform: rotate(0deg) }
to   { transform: rotate(360deg) }
}

body {
-moz-animation-name: roll;
-moz-animation-duration: 4s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-name: roll;
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

Comment: css prefixes were such a dumb idea.

Answer (score 3):

It's a CSS Transition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions

```
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
-moz-transition-property: all;
-moz-transition-duration: 5s;
```

Example for Mozilla above, use `-o` and `-webkit` to target other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

It uses custom CSS animations. See the CSS rules applied to the `<body>` here:

```
body {
    -moz-animation-name: roll;
    -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -o-animation-name: roll;
    -o-animation-duration: 4s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-name: roll;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a css3 rotation [transformation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform) applied to either the body or html tags

Answer (score 1):

Add a link with something like that:

```
javascript:(function(){var s=document.createElement('style');s.innerHTML='%40-moz-keyframes roll { 100%25 { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } } %40-o-keyframes roll { 100%25 { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); } } %40-webkit-keyframes roll { 100%25 { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } } body{ -moz-animation-name: roll; -moz-animation-duration: 4s; -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1; -o-animation-name: roll; -o-animation-duration: 4s; -o-animation-iteration-count: 1; -webkit-animation-name: roll; -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; }';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);}());
```

Answer (score 0):

This guy will do the trick on any webpage:

```
@-moz-keyframes roll {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) }
    to   { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) }
}
body {
    -moz-animation-name: roll;
    -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   }
```

Remember that this is for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

if you want infinite

```
 @-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
 @-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
 @keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
 body{-webkit-animation: spin 9.9s infinite linear;}
```