# Rotate table * degrees in HTML

Tags: html

Is it possible to rotate a table 30 degrees (and other degrees also) in HTML? If not is there a work around?

I'm normally an Excel VBA developer so this is new territory for me. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

What I am trying to do is create a table that is rotated with single letters in the table. Basically recreating an auditorium where the seats go around in blocks at different angles.

Comment: HTML contains data, CSS contains styles, JS contains interactions (MVC). Use CSS.

Comment: @JimGarrison — Not so obviously. No JavaScript [is involved in that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000194/how-does-google-do-the-barrel-roll).

Comment: I updated exactly what I am looking for in the question. I prefer to use little to no java script. recognisethis' answer seems to be the one I like the most like so far. I'll have to take time to look at it and make sure it works first though. Thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use CSS3 transforms for this. You will need to use the relevant browser prefixes to make it cross browser

[CSS3 Transforms](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. They are [dreadful](http://w3fools.com/). That page (at least the top of it) is above their usual level of quality, but they drop points for having the standard name *first* instead of last.